# How to access c++ dll class in c# code

Tags: c#, winapi, dllimport

I have a C++ class in my 3rd party dll.

If I call Assembly.LoadFrom(), VS throws up an unhandled exception as there is no manifest contained in the module.

I can call global functions using DllImport to get an instance of a certain class.

How do I then call one of its member functions?

Comment: take a look "Calling C++ Unmanaged Class from C#" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanpil/archive/2004/07/07/175855.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper DLL with C++/CLI exposing C++ functions

for example:

```
//class in the 3rd party dll
class NativeClass
{
    public:
    int NativeMethod(int a)
    {
        return 1;
    }   
};

//wrapper for the NativeClass
class ref RefClass
{
    NativeClass * m_pNative;

    public:
    RefClass():m_pNative(NULL)
    {
        m_pNative = new NativeClass();
    }

    int WrapperForNativeMethod(int a)
    {
        return m_pNative->NativeMethod(a);
    }

    ~RefClass()
    {
        this->!RefClass();
    }

    //Finalizer
    !RefClass()
    {
        delete m_pNative;
        m_pNative = NULL;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.LoadFrom is used to load managed assembly.

For unmanaged assemblies [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx) is required.

[How to Marshal c++ class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class)